# changing age using regex pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, replace

```
    import pandas as pd
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Data' : ['A 90-year-old or 96-year-old and 110-year-old is 90 days  ', 
                                       'For all 82-year-old is the 94-year-old why 28A ', 
                                       'But the fact is 101-year-old 109-year-old cool 100',],
                          'ID': [1,2,3]

                         })
#tried this regex
dataframe['New'] = dataframe['Data'].str.replace(r'\d+(-year-old)', r'>90')

dataframe
    Data                                                      ID    New
0   A 90-year-old or 96-year-old and 110-year-old is 90 days  1 A >90 or >90 and >90 is 90 days
1   For all 82-year-old is the 94-year-old why 28A            2 For all >90 is the >90 why 28A
2   But the fact is 101-year-old 109-year-old cool 100        3 But the fact is >90 >90 cool 100
```

I am trying to use regex to change all the ages that are above 90. So, `90-year-old` will be changed to `>90` for exampple. But `82-year-old` or any age under 90 shouldn't. I am close to what I want as seen above but `82-year-old` still get changed to `>90` but it shouldnt

How do I change my regex in this line of code

```
   dataframe['New'] = dataframe['Data'].str.replace(r'\d+(-year-old)', r'>90')
```

so that *only* `90-year-old` and above (e.g. `91-year-old`, `98-year-old`, `105-year-old`, etc )get changed to `>90`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify this with a regex that covers two cases: `9[1-9]` and `\d{3,}`:

```
dataframe['New'] = dataframe['Data'].str.replace(r'(9[1-9]|\d{3,})(-year-old)', r'>90')
```

The first part `9[1-9]` thus matches all values between `91` and `99`, the second part, all numbers with three digits or more (`1234` is of course *very* unlikely).

For the given sample data, we obtain:

```
>>> dataframe['Data'].str.replace(r'(9[1-9]|\d{3,})(-year-old)', r'>90')
0    A 90-year-old or >90 and >90 is 90 days  
1      For all 82-year-old is the >90 why 28A 
2             But the fact is >90 >90 cool 100
Name: Data, dtype: object
```

If you want to include `90`, you can change the regex to:

```
>>> dataframe['Data'].str.replace(r'(9\d|\d{3,})(-year-old)', r'>90')
0          A >90 or >90 and >90 is 90 days  
1    For all 82-year-old is the >90 why 28A 
2           But the fact is >90 >90 cool 100
Name: Data, dtype: object
```